# Why does Invoke-WebRequest not return a response in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops, response

We're running a PowerShell script in a DevOps release pipeline that does an API call via the 'Invoke-WebRequest' cmdlet.

The strange thing is that it does not seem to return a response in PowerShell upon first attempt to execute it. It seems stuck.

From browsing (F12) to the URI, used in the request, I get to see the error message "This page isn't working right now" and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()".

If we cancel the DevOps release and rerun this step, it does work. So on second attempt, same code, same API endpoint, it just works.

Here's a piece of the code

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($token)")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

[xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content $ConfigXml

$body =
@{
    _request = @{
        RequestTime = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        RequestUserSessionId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        ConfigurationXML = "$($xmlContent.InnerXml)"
        RequestId = "8fedcd4e-f401-4472-a9c9-d0e17ebb0d94"
    };
}

$enc = $body | ConvertTo-Json

try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest "$($DynamicsUri)/api/services/.../importSetup" -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $enc -UseBasicParsing
    Write-Host "Response: " $response
}
catch {
    $_.Exception.Message    
}
```

Has anyone experienced something like this before and how was it resolved please?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps there needs to be a slight delay before making the `Invoke-WebRequest`. Does anything change if you put `Start-Sleep -Seconds 60` at the top of your `try` block?

Comment: Write-Host accepts strings. Maybe $response.ToString() is null? If you run these commands in the shell instead of as a script, pipe $response to get-member and what is the result?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Adding a sleep did not do the trick

Comment: @tonypags Adding $response.something does not work. It's stuck in the API call. It never reaches the Write-Host.

Answer (score 0):

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
> ()".

This issue output represented the request sent by the client to the server lacks valid authentication credentials. It may occur client does not provide the proper authentication credentials to the server within the request time.

401 is the HTTP status code for authentication errors. And that’s just it: it’s for authentication, not authorization. Receiving a 401 response is the server telling you, “you aren’t authenticated–either not authenticated at all or authenticated incorrectly–but please reauthenticate and try again.” To help you out, it will always include a WWW-Authenticate header that describes how to authenticate.

**Http decision diagram**

https://www.loggly.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/http-decision-diagram.png

I suggest you focus on the 'Authorization' section. There might be a problem here.

Also, what operation do you mean by 'cancel the DevOps release', and what format is your request url?

Anyway, this error is related to the API you are calling. The root cause should be the credential.

Comment: Hi Bowman Zhu, sorry for the late reply. The issue is still occurring. The WWW-Authenticate header states **WWW-Authenticate: authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/.../oauth2/authorize", Bearer**.  From the question you can see that it's included in the header. In a test I've also outputted the $token value and it is correct.

Comment: To clarify on the 'DevOps release'... We have a release pipeline in DevOps executing several tasks. Those tasks execute a PowerShell script that does the API POST call. Task 1 generates a bearer token, this POST works. Task 2 uses that same bearer token, this POST fails with the error in the question. When we cancel the release pipeline, because it is stuck on the 2nd POST, and retry deployment of that 2nd POST, it does work.. No clue why this is happening.